# Basic examples of static and dynamic RAM

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-hardware

What could be the basic examples (or the one that we are familiar of) of static and dynamic RAM?

My Thoughts:
First of all $\color{RED}{\text{RAM}}$ is something whose contents will be lost if power is removed
Now, in $\color{green}{\text{Static RAM}}$, the contents of the memory do not change with time and they hold data as long as the D.C. power is applied and here we do not require any refreshing
whereas, $\color{blue}{\text{Dynamic RAM}}$ needs to be periodically refreshed otherwise their stored information will be lost
so one basic example of Static RAM may be an **unsaved Text file in MS Word** or an **unsaved screenshot in Paint software**
And one basic example of Dynamic RAM may be this site  https://mbasic.facebook.com which require refreshing for seeing new News feeds
These are my thoughts and I am not $100 \%$ sure
so please help...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory

Comment: No, applications and web sites are not very good analogies for SRAM and DRAM.  Refreshing a web page to get updates is totally different from refreshing DRAM to stop it from forgetting what's already there.  Refreshing a web page is more like a multi-cpu case with non-coherent cache.  (The server didn't invalidate your browser's copy of the page when the page changed.)